# Kill another application and clear it's data

Tags: android

I am working on a tool that kills selected application and clears all it's data. Sort of simulating [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28496/how-to-force-kill-android-applications-without-a-task-manager/)
I have only package name available.

Comment: do want to do it programmatically or want to do it using some apps ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am not sure whether it would work or not but what you can do is get the process ID of the app with the package name you have and then call `killProcess()` method with process ID as the parameter.

**EDIT1:-** ok.. forget whats written above.. I've tried the following code and it seems to work for me.

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
activityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(appProcessName);
```

You need to specify `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission in your application manifest and you are golden.

**EDIT2:-** the following piece of code clears app data. But there is a problem that it cant clear other app's data because every android app runs in a Sandbox, which shields their data from being accessed from outside its scope.

```
public void clearApplicationData(String packageName) {
        File cache = getCacheDir();
        File appDir1 = new File(cache.getParent()).getParentFile();
        File appDir = new File(appDir1.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + packageName);
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (String s : children) {
                if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
                    Toast.makeText(this, "App Data Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
        if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
                if (!success) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
```

It may be possible to change the files' permission by using `Process` class and executing `chmod` command through it but then again you'll need to run as shell for that package which requires the application to be set as debuggable in the `Android-Manifest` file.

So bottom-line is its tough if not impossible to clear other app's data.

Comment: Good.. Regarding the clear data part.. Will update the answer tomorrow morning (it's late night in India right now)

Comment: I tried running shell commands, but it is impossible without root access. Well, I had to try :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This seems highly impossible, in my opinion. Android does not allow you to kill (or clear data) of another application.

[This link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) specifies a method killBackgroundProcess( String ), however the kernel would not kill it unless it is your own package name.

Comment: That's what I believe, but then again, there _are_ task manager apps out there...

Comment: Yes, I must agree with Romiox