# Clear data of another application from my application

Tags: java, android

I want to delete another application data let's say I want to delete app data of facebook or whatsapp data from my application. 
I tried [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19831167/2591002), but as it;s said *it cant clear other app's data because every android app runs in a Sandbox, which shields their data from being accessed from outside its scope.*

So, is it possible that I can redirect the user to setting screen and explicitly click on clear data programmatically ?

My snippet :

```
 public void clearApplicationData(String packageName) {
    File cache = getCacheDir();
    File appDir1 = new File(cache.getParent()).getParentFile();
    File appDir = new File(appDir1.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + packageName);
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            if (!s.equals("lib")) {
                deleteDir(new File(appDir, s));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}



  List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    clearApplicationData(packageInfo.packageName);
```

[image]

Comment: "is it possible that I can redirect the user to setting screen and explicitly click on clear data programmatically ?" -- no.

Comment: So, you mean to say there is no possibility to implement such mechanism that will clear other app's data?

Comment: You need a special system permission which you cannot get. E.g. try to run in a shell from an app `pm install some.apk` it will fail with that permission you cannot get. While you use adb this will work.